# Strategy behind this chess position?

Tags: endgame, puzzles, queen-endgame

I am only used to check-in-n type of puzzle, so I am quite lost when my friend challenge me to this endgame position. EDIT: figured out how to do the chess board (note: the board seemed to be flipped, the black pawn should be close to queening)

=====

Can Black win?
Black move first.

```
[fen "8/7Q/7K/8/8/kp6/qp6/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

=====

It seemed very obviously that black should win, with an advantage of 2 nearly queening pawns. Yet the way the question is asked make me think otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Nalimov Endgame Tablebase: http://www.k4it.de/?topic=egtb&lang=en this position is a win in 40 moves for black, if black promotes for a knight to block the upcoming avalanche of checks.
However if black promotes for a queen it's a draw.

Comment: I wish there are more intuitive way to explain the solution (there are still a lot of random stuff happening afterward), but I guess this will do.